# Merging two MYSQL queries. Using a subquery with multiple rows in a where clause

Tags: mysql

Despite being a total newbie to subqueries i thought I could merge two sql queries into one.
I am currently selecting

```
SELECT tB.Aid AS AID FROM tB JOIN tA ON tB.Aid=tA.id WHERE
tB.somefield=1 AND tA.anyfield=1 GROUP BY tB.Aid
```

And then LOOPING for every resulting row with (AID):

```
SELECT tB.* FROM tB WHERE tB.Aid=AID
```

I tried to merge these queries using:

```
SELECT tB.* FROM tB WHERE tB.Aid=(SELECT tB.Aid FROM tB JOIN tA ON
tB.Aid=tA.id WHERE tB.somefield=1 AND tA.anyfield=1 GROUP BY tB.Aid)
```

But the error message is

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

which was what I wanted but mysql cant handle it. Is it possibly to write this in some other way, using only one sql query?

Do I have to explain my intention with my Query further, or is it clear what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it slightly differently and you can join both result sets :

```
SELECT b1.*
  FROM (
           SELECT b.Aid AS AID
             FROM tB b JOIN tA a ON b.Aid=a.id 
            WHERE b.somefield=1
              AND a.anyfield=1
         GROUP BY b.Aid
       ) sq 
  JOIN tB b1 ON (b1.Aid = sq.AID)
```

Comment: This also works as expected and seems to be faster too. So far I have small datasets but there was a 34% decrease in executiontime comparing to the IN statements solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must change `where column_name = (SUBQUERY)` to `where column_name IN (SUBQUERY)`, but it would be probably better to use a JOIN between the two queries instead of an IN (at least in most cases).

Comment: So IN has performance issues, but not more than my original double sql query I guess?

Comment: tried the JOIN solution suggested and it seems to be a little faster.

Comment: It is a little faster because your database is probably small at this time. Let it grow and you'll probably find a huge advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Use **IN** keywords

```
    SELECT tB.* FROM tB WHERE tB.Aid IN (SELECT tB.Aid FROM tB JOIN tA ON
tB.Aid=tA.id WHERE tB.somefield=1 AND tA.anyfield=1 GROUP BY tB.Aid)
```